# How to flash openthread for EFR32 without JLink

Tags: gcc, openthread

I am trying to build OpenThread(NCP mode) and upload program to EFR32 without JLink.

EFR32 can support OTA upload method and supported format is "ebl".

My propose is：

1. Adding cstartup-common.c into compile script
2. Build to "axf" format by adding "-gdwarf-2" option on arm-none-eabi-gcc.
3. Using "arm-none-eabi-objcopy.exe --srec-forceS3 -O srec ot-ncp-ftd.axf ot-ncp-ftd.s37" to convert "axf" -> "s37"
4. Using Silabs' tool "commander.exe" to convert "s37" -> "ebl"
5. Using "flash_firmware" tool to upload "ebl" file from host chip to EFR32 by UART

I meet the following error log when runing "wpantund" on host chip

*- "The NCP is 
misbehaving: Repeatedly unable to initialize NCP. Entering fault state."*

Is there any one know this?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have loaded something onto your part before, Silicon Labs chips don't come with a bootloader from the factory. The initial programming of an EFR32 must come via J-Link or the Silicon Labs WSTK.

How are you interfacing this chip? You mention UART, but via what interface?